# Explanation for cross product observation

Tags: vectors, cross-product

For a dynamics class, I have observed a weird correlation which my Professor couldn't explain.
So I was wondering if someone would give me an explanation of what's happening .

Here's a general example to explain my query.

Given two Vectors $$ \hat{\mathbf{a}}=3\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{k} ,\hat{\mathbf{b}} =2\mathbf{i}+2\mathbf{k} $$ at planes situated at $$ \mathbf{j}=2,\mathbf{j}=4 $$ , we are required to find the magnitude and angle $\theta $ of a vector $\mathbf{F}$ situated in plane at $$ \mathbf{j}=6 $$ such that 
$$ (2\mathbf{j} \times \hat{\mathbf{a}}) +4\mathbf{j}  \times (\hat{\mathbf{b}}) = 6\mathbf{j}\times \mathbf{F}$$

Weirdly enough(to me) I found that the difference between the angle calculated via the polar form of the L.H.S of the above equation and 90 degrees gives me the correct angle $\theta$ required.

**Question**
Is there a valid reason as to why such a thing even works?

Comment: This should be migrated to Math.SE

Comment: @JohnRennie this question was initially posted there, I just put it here as well because I didn't get any answers from there.I reasoned ,people here are applied mathematicians .

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying that if you express $(2\mathbf{j} \times \hat{\mathbf{a}}) +(4\mathbf{j}  \times \hat{\mathbf{b}})$ in polar notation ($r_{ab}$, $\theta_{ab}$) and $\vec{F}$ as ($r_F$, $\theta_F$), then $\theta_F = 90 - \theta_{ab}$?

Comment: @JohnRennie Spot on. EXcept it's $\theta_{F}=\theta_{ab} -90$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. Look at this diagram:

[image: Vectors]

You found that $\theta_F = \theta_{ab} - 90$. But we know that:

$$ (2\mathbf{j} \times \hat{\mathbf{a}}) +(4\mathbf{j}  \times \hat{\mathbf{b}}) = 6\mathbf{j}\times \mathbf{F} $$

so $\theta_{ab} = \theta_{6j\times F}$. Because $\vec{6j}$ is normal to the $ik$ plane the vector $6j \times \vec{F}$ lies in the $ik$ plane at 90 degrees to $\vec{F}$. That automatically means that to get from $\theta_{6j\times F}$ to $\theta_F$ you rotate by -90 degrees.

Comment: shouldn't the vectors in the diagram be interchanged so the rotation by -90 degrees make sense?

Comment: I quite possibly got the direction of $6j \times F$ wrong - I did it in a hurry. What did you get for $F$?

Comment: the $(2 \mathbf{j}\times\hat{a} + 4\mathbf{j} \times \hat{b})$  is a vector angled at 305 $^\circ$ and the $\mathbf{F}$  is angled at 215.54 $^\circ$